# Setting MPMediaItem's artwork

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I know I can retrieve an `MPMediaItem`'s artwork by doing the following:

```
MPMediaItemCollection *collection;
/* Get media item collection here */
MPMediaItem *item = [[collection items] objectAtIndex:0];
MPMediaItemArtwork *artwork = [item valueForKey:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
```

I would like to replace the artwork image with another. How would I accomplish this?

I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
UIImage *newImage;
/* get image here */
MPMediaItemArtwork *artwork = [[MPMediaItemArtwork alloc] initWithImage:newImage];
[item setValue:artwork forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
```

An run-time exception is thrown with the following message:
`this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key artwork.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MPMediaItems are immutable - you can't change anything in the iPod library using the API.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/AboutiPodLibraryAccess/AboutiPodLibraryAccess.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008765-CH103-SW9

Comment: can i create my custom `MPMediaItem` and set the required property then play in my custom player ? is it possible ?